# How do you specify OrderBy clause on two columns

Tags: hibernate, jpa, seam

We would like to orderBy 2 columns in the Seam EntityQuery interface as well as the JPA model. How do we do this?

```
@Entity
public class A{

@OrderBy(???) // should this be hardcoded here, is it database agnostic
List<B> bobjects;
}

@Entity
public class B {

   public short startTimeHrs;
   public short startTimeMins;
}

@Name("bList")
public class B extends EntityQuery {
        setOrderColumn("startTimeHrs, startTimeMins"); // Is this correct?
        setOrderDirection("asc");
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are talking about `javax.persistence.OrderBy`, this annotation takes into parameter a list of comma separated properties (of the target entity) and order the collection accordingly. For example in your case, `startTimeHrs asc, startTimeMins asc`.

From the JPA 1.0 specification:

> #### 9.1.28 OrderBy Annotation
>
> The `OrderBy` annotation specifies the
>   ordering of the elements of a
>   collection valued association at the
>   point when the association is
>   retrieved.
>
> ```
> @Target({METHOD, FIELD}) @Retention(RUNTIME)
> public @interface OrderBy {
> String value() default "";
> }
> ```
>
> The syntax of the value ordering
>   element is an orderby_list, as
>   follows:
>
> ```
> orderby_list::= orderby_item [,orderby_item]*
> orderby_item::= property_or_field_name [ASC | DESC]
> ```
>
> If `ASC` or `DESC` is not specified,
>   `ASC` (ascending order) is assumed.
>
> If the ordering element is not
>   specified, ordering by the primary key
>   of the associated entity is assumed.
>
> The property or field name must
>   correspond to that of a persistent
>   property or field of the associated
>   class. The properties or fields used
>   in the ordering must correspond to
>   columns for which comparison operators
>   are supported.

Answer (score 13):

Yes you can use `@OrderBy` to order your queries.

```
@OrderBy("startTimeHrs, startTimeMins")
@OneToMany(...)
getBobjects() {
   return bobjects;
}
```

Now whenever you are saying `A.getBobjects()` they will be ordered. However, if you are using the EntityQuery way of retrieving the result you can override the `getEjbql()` and put the order by there.

```
@Name("bList")
public class B extends EntityQuery {
    @Override
    public String getEjbql() {
          return "select b from B b order by startTimeHrs, startTimeMins";
    }
}
```

Or you can `@Override` the `getResultList()` to manipulate the collection there in your entityLists

Comment: I wouldn't want to override the getResultList method here. Would you specify the orderBy direction as part of Ejbql or via the setOrderDirection(..) method?

Comment: That's up to you. You can do everything in the ejbql